# HTML5 audio/video loading issue in Android browsers

Tags: android, html, caching, audio, html5-video

I'm doing a project in **HTML** 5, targeting **android tablets**. There are some jquery animations which are triggered using audio **timeupdate** delegate.

It works fine but shows some loading issues while navigating through pages.
It wont load sometimes. I added a loader in **$(document).ready();** method and will be removed in **canplaythrough** delegate.

Sometimes loader wont disappear since the **canplaythrough** is not called.

Issue cannot be find frequently. **Why audio is not properly loaded everytime?** Is this because of the **browser caching**?

I'm testing it in both Android default and chrome browsers.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With these kind of things you should be really carefull to have in your mind the exact timeline the page will walk through and what happens at each point. Just like directing an orchestra.
That is why I don't use Jquery for these kind of things but my own written functions to set up the timing so that I know exactly what happens at what point, without it being hidden by the jquery processing which I don't know and is subject to change when jquery updates.
Try replacing the timers with your own functions if noone gives a good answer that works for you.

Comment: hi @MichaelDibbets, thanks for your suggestion. But using time update doesn't make any issue. Issue is with the loading. I think browsers are trying to cache the audio elements. that's why it' not loaded sometimes. I couldn't find any proper solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I found the "**abort**" method is called during the "error loading" case, But not the "**error**" method. And then I checked the "**readyState**" values. It shows "0"( **HAVE_NOTHING**) value. I tried to **refresh the page** in such cases. It seems **working but** it'll be a **bad practice** as the user can see the **browser is trying refresh the page** several times. Is it possible to **reload audio object**.